# ImmutableJS deep setting an object

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, immutable.js

I am trying to set the value of an immutable object using `.set()`. The value updates as it should, but I can't fetch from the object using `.getIn()` afterwards. I think this is because it's not deep setting the children of the object as immutable. Is there any method in immutable.js that will allow me to do this? I know I can wrap the object in `fromJS()` like `.set(fromJS('rooms', roomMap))` but this seems messy. What is the correct way to do this?

```
  const state = Immutable.fromJS({
      rooms: false
  });

  const roomMap = 
  {
      "roomid1": {
          "id": "roomid1",
          "name": "Room 101",
      },
      "roomid2": {
          "id": "roomid2",
          "name": "Room 102",
      },
  };

  var newState = state.set('rooms', roomMap);
  console.log(newState.getIn(['rooms', 'roomid1']));;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z0a4p199/1/

Comment: That is what the `fromJS` function is for though. Either that your you build up every nested collection using their respective `Map` or `List` functions, but this seems unreasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your room map is a plain javascript object, not an immutalblejs map.

Hence, when you do `state.set('rooms', roomMap)` you are setting the value of rooms to a plain javascript object.

`newState.getIn(['rooms', 'roomid1'])`: this works only when the newState is a javascript object completely.

You have to either conver the roomMap into an immutablejs map or access the roomid1 in plain javascript way.

Alternative 1:

```
roomMap = Immutable.fromJS(roomMap)
state.update('rooms', (oldvalue)=>(roomMap))
newState.getIn(['rooms', 'roomid1'])
```

Alternative 2:

```
newState.get('rooms').roomid1
```

[JS Filddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z0a4p199/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `set` with Nested Structures created by `fromJS`.

You will need to use either `mergeDeep` or `updateIn`. In your case, you will have to use `mergeDeep`

```js
const state = Immutable.fromJS({
  rooms: false
});
console.log(state.get('rooms'));

const roomMap = {
  "roomid1": {
    "id": "roomid1",
    "name": "Room 101",
  },
  "roomid2": {
    "id": "roomid2",
    "name": "Room 102",
  },
};

const newState = state.mergeDeep({
  rooms: roomMap
});
console.log(newState.get('rooms'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.min.js"></script>
```